# Constructor which takes no arguments but still assigns values?(java)

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I have some trouble with constructor in MyNewSong class. Can anyone explain what exactly it is doing? As i understood it takes no parameters from the super class, but it returns the song name "First Song" to a super class, is it correct? The child class does not have it's own song field so all it does is assigns the song name to the super class name field, is that correct? I just haven't seen non empty(default) constructor before which doesn't take parameters but still assigns values.

Thank you!

```
public class Song {
    private String name;

    public Song(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

```
public class MyNewSong extends Song {
    public MyNewSong() {
        super("First Song");
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, the song name being passed is a hard coded strring literal so it doesn't need to be passed in. Plus, the parent constructor is what's setting the value and it does take a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MyNewSong` class is a subclass of `Song`. So, an instance of `MyNewSong` is itself a `Song`. According to your code, every `Song` has a `name`. The constructor for `MyNewSong` passes `"My First Song"` to the super class constructor as the song name. So, all instances of `MyNewSong` have the same `name`, specifically `"My First Song"`.

I recommend you read more about [inheritance in the Java Tutorials](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjt78_M3ZHMAhUJ8CYKHaS9CjMQFggjMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2Ftutorial%2Fjava%2FIandI%2Fsubclasses.html&usg=AFQjCNE1M-CDeBP5SJNeMrYltsz8ouz8XA&sig2=Lw7evyLb1F_eayS-gxIm3g).

Answer (score 1):

When MyNewSong is instanciated it passes "First Song" to the super constructor which assigns it to "name". There is nothing strange in this construct. Since the access to name is "private" and there are no public/protected methods accessing the field the "name" attribute will not be visible to the subclass. The reason you see negative vote is because you should do more reading before posting questions.

Answer (score 1):

The new song class is inheriting the properties of Song class. The command:

```
super("First Song");
```

is passing the argument "First Song" as argument to the constructor of the superclass Song.

Comment: There should be no problem understanding this logic.